# Unable to deserialize object in 64bit

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I am getting the following exception when i try to deserialize an object using BinaryFormatter if i run the application in 64bit

Exception The constructor to deserialize an object of type  was not found

It works perfectly if I force the app to run in 32bit mode. 
The object i am de-serializing implements the ISerializable interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unlikely to be anything to do with 64-bit. An example would go a very long way, but: in the case of `BinaryFormatter` and `ISerializable`, it is required that you also provide a constructor taking (as parameters) `SerializationInfo` and `StreamingContext`. It sounds like one way or another, your type is missing this. So: make sure it is there.

Comment: i definately have a constructor taking the parameters SerializationInfo and StreamingContext. This is very strange to me.

Comment: @Alvin unfortunately, without something to look at there is not much we can say

Comment: After doing some testing, I think the reason why it failed has to do with this 3rd party libary i am using. I believe it is built using 32bit. Do all dlls have to be in 64 bit? thanks

Comment: @Alvin it could be in AnyCpu or AnyCpuPrefer32Bit - then it would work in either, but to be honest this shouldn't usually impact this.

Comment: i think the 3rd party library was built with x86 mode and not AnyCpu, because i get an exception System.BadImageFormatException. Could not load file or assembly. Is there a way to tell which mode it is built in?

Comment: ok i downloaded this program called dotpeek, and it says its x86.. so i think i need to find a new dll...

Comment: @Alvin unless you have a reason to think this is related, I suspect you are leaping to conclusions

Comment: The 3rd party library i am using is QuickFix .net. I dont' think there is a 64bit version for it yet.

Comment: @Alvin and I'm saying: I'm not sure that should affect serialization. But: if you want a cross-platform/framework serializer, I'll recommend protobuf-net (but: I'm somewhat biased)

Comment: Actually i do use profobuf.net for something else.It is great! But this object i am trying to serialize and deserialize is old and it contains an object in QuickFix. When i try to serialize it using the binary formatter on a 64bit machine, I get the System.BadImageFormatException. All my dlls are ANYCPU, apart from that Quickfix library.

Comment: @Alvin hmm, bad-image *could* indeed be this - but this is the first time you've mentioned that :)

Comment: Yes. Unforunately, when i first made this post I was serializing on a 32bit machine and then sending it to a 64bit machine. So i didn't get that error before. But yesterday I tried to test serializing on a 64bit machine too, and i got that exception.  Thanks for your help!